# accidentally clobbered directory using `mv` instead of `mv -t`

Tags: linux, mv, inode

I accidentally did

- `mv file /an/important/directory`

instead of

- `mv file /an/important/directory/` or
- `mv file -t /an/important/directory`,

so it now looks like `/an/important/directory/` is clobbered. (I thought I† `alias`ed `mv` to `mv -i` to prevent this kind of thing…)

But my filesystem is not smaller, making me think the files have not actually moved and I could do something to an inode to help the system find and organise those non-deleted files again.

---

**Added:** since [same drive](https://superuser.com/questions/259097/what-happens-if-mv-is-interrupted) is apparently important, I should add that `/media/target.folder` is what I clobbered. I was trying to move stuff off `/dev/sda1`.

---

† **`sudo mv`:** oh wait. I didn't `alias mv=mv -i` in `/home/root/.bash_aliases` *as well as* in `~/.bash_aliases`. `sudo mv` likely calls the root version. Whoops.

---

**UPDATE:** Per @HackSlash’s comment, here is what my `/media` directory looks like:

```
i@scheherezade:/media$ ls -oh
total 80K
drwxr-xr-x   4 root 4.0K Jul 26 16:17 backup
drwxr-xr-x   2 root 4.0K Dec  8  2016 DEIMOS
drwxrwxrwx  69 mars 4.0K Mar 14 13:20 PHOBOS
drwxr-xr-x 113 i     56K Jul 26 18:10 media
drwxr-xr-x   4 root 4.0K Mar 31 08:43 opt
drwxrwxr-x   7 i    4.0K Mar 30 17:27 puck
```

I was trying to move `file` to `/media/media`, where the first `/media` is the system saying "things that are mounted", and the second `/.../media` is *me* saying "video and audio files". Something is clearly different about `/media/media`, but I don’t know if this answers @HackSlash’s suggestion about symlinks.

Comment: mv won't clobber a directory that easily. You just moved the file into it.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley When I did `ls -oh /an/important/`, it showed that the directory had become the renamed file.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Also, `ls -oh/an/important/directory` now does not contain anything.

Comment: Wumpus is correct: `Note: mv will only replace empty directories in the destination. Conflicting populated directories are skipped with a diagnostic. ` https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mv-invocation.html

Comment: You likely have a typo somewhere

Comment: OR: Was that directory a symlink or softlink?

Comment: @HackSlash even in that case the file is moved to it and doesn't overwrite the link.

Comment: @HackSlash what kind of typo do you mean?

Comment: @HackSlash Yes, it may have been, because it's in `/media`, which I think is controlled by symlinks

Comment: If it's a mount point then the files could be under the mount point. If they aren't in the physical location that is mounted then that is what I would check next. Unmount the media and then look at the location again. You will see that the contents has changed.

Answer (score 0):

What happened was: I had tried to `mv /some/file /media/backup` without `mount /dev/sd1 /media/backup` really being `mount`ed. (When I close my laptop, network and USB hard drives disconnect.) So files were actually being copied to `/dev/sda1` 's root `/` tree, one layer down in a folder called `/media`. (I had to back up with `sudo` anyway, so the user-vs-`root` protection didn't stop me.) In turn, files in `/media/backup` (which was really `/dev/sda1`) were not behaving like the connected peripheral device I thought they were.

I used `lsblk -f` to see which things really were mounted, and where. (You can also use `df -h /media/backup/` to see which UUID a folder is on. ( `cat /proc/*some*file*I*forget*which*` shows this information too.)

`lsblk -f` also tells me the names of the hardware volumes, which I've chosen to match the names of the mount points under `/media/*/`. To prevent confusion between the old putative `/media/*/` `mount`s and the new correct mounts, I mounted `/dev/sdk1` etc to `/mnt/sdk1/`.

Then `mv` behaves as expected.

---

This is on Ubuntu.