# Linux: how to move a large file tree, deleting files during the copy (not after)

Tags: linux, coreutils

I'd like to encrypt a disk in-place, from clear to ecryptfs (not boot disk, just disk with lots of data files).

I've created the following structure:

```
  /mnt/
   clear/ # the source files
   cipher/ # the ecryptfs ciphertext directory
   mounted.clear/ # the mounted ecryptfs directory
```

I'd like to do something like:
`mv /mnt/clear/* /mnt/mounted.clear/`

The problem is that since this is a cross-filesystem move, mv will first copy then unlink each argument (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/259097/what-happens-if-mv-is-interrupted)). I don't have enough free space on this disk to duplicate some of the subdirectories under `/mnt/clear`.

I wish there was an `mv --delete-during` argument (or similar), but there isn't (not in GNU coreutils 8.3 anyway :). Any other *easy* ideas? I could write a quick script to do it, but would rather not if there's an easier solution/utility I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option of `rsync`:

> `--remove-source-files`
> This tells `rsync` to remove from the sending side the files (meaning non-directories) that are a part of the transfer and have been successfully duplicated on the receiving side.

```
rsync -av --remove-source-files /mnt/clear/ /mnt/mounted.clear
```

My tests indicate the tool removes files on the fly, not at the end.

Notes:

- The slash (`/`) after `/mnt/clear` is important.
- "Successfully duplicated" means you should lose nothing, even if there are problems.
- You will need to remove directories in a separate step. Use `find /mnt/clear/ ! -type d` to make sure there are no stale non-directories.

---

If you cannot use `rsync`, consider this option of `tar`:

> `--remove-files`
> Remove files from disk after adding them to the archive.

```
cd /mnt/mounted.clear/ &&
( cd /mnt/clear/ && tar -vc --remove-files * ) | tar -x
```

My tests indicate the first `tar` removes files on the fly, not at the end. There are pitfalls though:

- You would want the first `tar` to postpone removing a file until it is safely written in the destination directory. No way. The tool cannot know what happens in the remaining part of the pipe. As soon as it processes a file, it removes it. It may happen the second `tar` lags behind, data accumulates in the pipe buffer, the first `tar` eagerly removes files. In such case if the second `tar` fails for whatever reason then the pipe will break and the buffered content (from some already removed files) will be lost. Reducing the buffer (e.g. with `stdbuf`) may minimize damage but I'm not sure if you can make the solution totally safe.

  <sup>I deliberately didn't use `cd … && tar … | ( cd … && tar … )`. In this version a possible failure of the second `cd` may occur after the first `tar` processes and removes something. In the original code both `cd` commands must succeed before the first `tar` runs.</sup>
- `*` doesn't match files starting with `.`.

---

Additional note:

- In my tests files disappeared from directory listings with delay, i.e. few moments (sometimes a minute) after `rsync` or `tar` processed them. I use Btrfs and I suspect this is its quirk.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! Two suggestions: (1) I think you meant `find ... -type f`, not `d` (to ensure there are no files); (2) why not use `tar -C` to change directories?

Comment: @YanivAknin (1) It's not `-type d`, it's `! -type d`. (2) No reason for you, I guess. Frankly I forgot about `tar -C`.